# What are golf ball holes called?

Tags: word-request

What are golf ball holes called? I thought the word for it was pot, but pot refers to pot bunkers which are sandy area in a golf course. Is there a better word for "golf ball holes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the hole that the ball goes into, it's usually just called a "hole", like the 9th hole. Maybe "golf hole" if you really need to make it clear. Never "golf ball hole".

Comment: The thing the ball goes into is called a cup. The part of the course leading up to a particular cup is called a hole, as you say. And the balls have dimples.

Comment: Oh yeah, cup is another useful word to describe the physical object. I don't think it's universal, though.